# How to print only disk usage percentage of linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, diskspace

How to print only disk usage percentage of linux similar to memory percentage.

for memory percentage i'm using this command:

```
free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "%.2f\t", $3*100/$2 }'
```

output:

```
12.17
```

like this is there any command for knowing disk usage percentage ?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/64815/203203

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`df`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/df.1.html):

```
$ df
Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs          1936588          0   1936588   0% /dev
tmpfs             1957840       7496   1950344   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs              783140       1864    781276   1% /run
/dev/sda6       518603776   12601324 504532516   3% /
tmpfs             1957844      27848   1929996   2% /tmp
/dev/sda6       518603776   12601324 504532516   3% /home
/dev/sda5          999320     289900    640608  32% /boot
tmpfs              391568       1696    389872   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1      1953512032 1952705324    806708 100% /run/media/mhawke/Seagate Expansion Drive
```

For one mount point:

```
$ df /boot
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5         999320 289900    640608  32% /boot
```

Percent usage:

```
$ df --output=pcent /boot
Use%
 32%
```

Excluding header:

```
$ df --output=pcent /boot | grep -v Use
 32%
$ usage=$(df --output=pcent /boot | grep -v Use)
$ echo $usage
32
```